# User login information not pulling active users

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Need some help on this.

I have a job that pulls user logins once a day and inserts into a table. The purpose of this is to gather user info to see what accounts can be dropped after a while.

```
Insert into [User_Login_Audit]
    Select 
        login_name, max (login_time) as last_login_time,     
        last_successful_logon, (select @@servername) as server_instance, getdate()
    from 
        sys.dm_exec_sessions 
    group by 
        login_name, last_successful_logon;
```

I am using the query below to gather the user information using registered servers.

```
SELECT 
    [Login_name],
    MAX([last_login_time]) AS Last_login_date,
    [server_instance],
    DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), max([last_login_time])) Days
FROM 
    [Benefitfocus_DBA].[dbo].[User_Login_Audit]
WHERE
    Login_name NOT IN ('NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'sa','')
    AND last_successful_logon IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    Login_name, server_instance
```

I've noticed that the top query pulls all information from `sys.dm_exec_sessions`. Some of the logins it records have been removed from security on that instance. I need only the users that are Active and / or present on the instance. Can someone suggest a way to either modify the Insert query to pull only users currently in security on the instance or a way on the second query to sort which users are active on the instance?

I would appreciate any insight into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few things I found that adding the following in the first collection script limited it to the current users:

```
where login_name in (SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals where type<>'R')
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [sys.server_principals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx) and see if it will work for you. You would do a join on the 'name' column in that table from the login_name that you currently have in your query. I'm not sure if you are deleting the logins or disabling them, but that system view could tell you if either condition was true.

The big caveat that I know of is that if a user has access to the server through an Active Directory group, you will find the login_name of the user in your current query but it will not match up to anything in the system view because the relevant entry there will be for the AD group. There are some ways to handle that, but not knowing if that is even relevant in your system I will not go into detail here.

Comment: I think my problem is with the AD group then.  It would makes sense in what I am seeing.  It makes me wonder if I can tie the user login to the group that was used.

Comment: You can query Active Directory with t-sql ... you can Google that for more info or ask a follow-up question if you need specific help on it.  You would need to iterate through the groups to get membership and then cross reference that.  I would personally do that kind of thing through an application layer but you could do all of this from within a SQL batch.